# Using renderOption in MUI's AutoComplete

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Today I come to you with a question that has been bugging me this past few days or so.

I am trying to make it so my autocomplete shows a label in the option, but the value is different. And so I googled around and found out you can do it with renderOption.
So I tried renderOption and I can't get it to work at all, and it's throwing me a error that I do not understand.

My code below:

```
    const itemList = [
        { value: "Car Winner", id: "casinofob" },
        { value: "PD 556", id: "-2084633992" },
        { value: "Cluckin Drink", id: "cbdrink" },
        { value: "Blink", id: "spellbook-blink" },
    ];

                        <Autocomplete
                          disablePortal
                          id="combo-box-demo"
                          options={itemList}
                          renderOption={option => <>{option.value}</>}
                          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.id}
                          sx={{ width: 300 }}
                          renderInput={(params) => <TextField onChange={updateSpawnEnteredItem} label="Item Name" sx={{marginBottom: '15px', marginTop:'5px', width: 300 }} {...params} />}
                    />
```

The error I am getting is as follows: "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes'

If anyone can help me solve this error, I'd be eternally grateful since I've had this problem for days now.

Regards.

Answer (score 27):

You need to pass the props along and return an `li` element.

Here is a more complex example where option has two properties:

```
interface AcOption {code: string, description: string}

<Autocomplete
  multiple
  id="ac-field-id"
  autoComplete={true}
  options={acOptions || []}
  loading={acOptionsLoading}
  filterSelectedOptions={true}
  groupBy={(option) => option?.code?.[0] || ''}
  isOptionEqualToValue={(option: AcOption, value: AcOption) => option.code === value.code}
  onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
    setInputAcOption(newInputValue)
  }}
  onChange={handleAcOptionChange}
  value={state.acOptions || []}
  filterOptions={(x) => x}
  getOptionLabel={(option: AcOption) => option?.code || ''}
  renderOption={(props, option: AcOption) => (
    <li {...props}>{option.code}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{option.description}</li>
  )}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="AC Option" />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: I am seeing that this should be wrapped in an array.
```  renderOption={(props, option: AcOption) => [
    <li {...props}>{option.code}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{option.description}</li>
  ]}```

Answer (score 8):

you need to pass props

```
 renderOption={(props: object, option: any, state: object) => (
        <div className={styles.option} {...props}>
           {option.name}
        </div>
  )}
```

Comment: This was my issue, everything else looked fine but I forgot to include `{...props}` and it caused the whole thing to break.

Comment: this is what fixed it for us! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The signature of `renderOption` is incorrect in your code. To render `option.value`, try the code below:

```js
<Autocomplete
  renderOption={(props, option) => <>{option.value}</>}
/>
```

Source: [renderOption - Autocomplete API](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/#:%7E:text=group%20to%20render.-,renderOption,-func)